# MongoDB using DDD coming from RDBMS World advice

Tags: c#, mongodb, domain-driven-design, ef-core-3.0

I am writting an application and it was all going well using RDBMS, but I could know that what I was doing was a candidate for a NoSql database.

I am prototyping an app where you swipe persons and you will eventually have matches. But I have some questions that I can't grasp now that I landed into a NoSql world and they are being hard to get out from my head..

For example, because I will swipe left and right I wanna put those personIds as References Resources in each person into the same collection (person) but designing my DDD model is being harsh.

My model is at the moment something like:

```
public class Person
{
    private List<Guid> personsNotInterestedRefs = new List<Guid>();
   
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public PersonName Name { get; private set; }        

    public IReadOnlyList<Guid> PersonsNotInterestedRefs
    {
        get => personsNotInterestedRefs.AsReadOnly();
        private set { personsNotInterestedRefs = value.ToList(); }
    }
   
    public Person(PersonName name, PersonAge age, PersonGender gender)
    {
        this.Age = age;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Gender = gender;
    }

    public Person Swipe(Guid other, FeelForPerson feel)
    {
        switch (feel)
        {
            case FeelForPerson.NotLiked:
                personsNotInterestedRefs.Add(other);
                break;
            case FeelForPerson.Liked:
               ..
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

In the RDBMS world I would use EF Core just with Domain objects (no ids present) and when I was creating an entity those items in those collections when SaveChanges would be called it will be persisted, but in Mongo as far as I know we don't have a Context the same was EF works, but collections and method to work with the collections, so I would do something like this at repository level:

```
  var filter = Builders<Person>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, person.Id);
        var update = Builders<Person>.Update.PushEach(p => p.PersonsInterestedRefs, person.PersonsInterestedRefs);
        personsCollection.FindOneAndUpdate(filter, update);
```

But this code does not belong to Person itself. I mean using EF we would just do the changes at domain level and EF would be respnsable for sending the commands and updating in DB and synchronizing my model, but with Mongo we need to update it manually? If yes, where would be the place? Where should we keep in sync with the DDD and the updates?

I think I am missing big one here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer would be that in NoSQL, one aggregate is stored in a single document. This means that the whole collection would be stored within the `Person`'s document, not on a different collection. This will present a problem possibly, because the list of matches will be evergrowing, potentially making your application fail at some point in the future, due to very large aggregates.

The way I approach DDD is mostly domain-model design first and technology second. Most of the time, when you get your domain quite right, the technology isn't a problem. All this to say, that I would start by exploring the possibility that your model is not fully correct to understand why MongoDb presents a problem.

The following is just an example of how I would explore the domain design:

Do we need `Person` to manage the list of matches? Will there be any business logic belonging to `Person` that relies on the information on the whole collection and that needs to be executed transactionally?

On the other hand, wouldn't a `Match` be more important in matching application than a simple record within a collection within an aggregate? Could we ever get a feature request like "When PersonA likes PersonB and PersonB already liked PersonA, do X"? How are we going to implement this type of feature if the match from PersonA to PersonB is in a different aggregate than the match from PersonB to PersonA?

Maybe we could make the `Match(PersonA, PersonB)` an Aggregate which holds the `FeelForPerson` in both directions, so that it can execute the required business logic on all scenarios.

With this design, we don't have the problem of an aggregate having to maintain an external collection or, if the collection is within the aggregate, the problem of it becoming too big. Every time we get a `Swipe` command (which will contain PersonA.Id and PersonB.Id) a use case will either create a `Match(PersonA, PersonB)` or load an existing one, execute a business operation on it and store it. `Person` doesn't really need to be involved in these operations.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply and your time giving your point. I can understand your point. I will also need to have a list of persons I have already swiped to not show the same users to the person again. In SQL i would have a table of all persons I have swiped and when searching for Persons I will exclude those ids from the Search, but with this approach how I would keep this list? I would simply query for example all persons that have liked me to create a match? In SQL my id would be an index and I would quickly know who liked me or not, here I would query Match looking for my id?

Comment: I also have the problem with the updates... Say for example I have a method in this DDD model, called finalize, which finalizes the state of the Match entity, which is when the second person swipes you and we are indicating the match is finalized, I can update some fields in this method like IsMatch set to true if both liked, but then at repository level I also need to use Builders and update the fields? I know I can update the whole document, so what is the point PushAll in Builders.Update<>. With EF Core this responsabilities were up to the ORM.

Comment: Regarding the list issue, note that handling the swipe and other Commands is a very different concern than Querying who to show to a user. CQRS is very powerful here because you can solve both problems independently, instead of trying to create a solution that kind of works for both. My answer tries to solve the Command part, where you apply your business logic. To Query the next possible matches, I wouldn't use the same tables. Consider if this app is successful, with tens of millions of users, your query logic and technology will be very specific. Excluding existing matches won't be your

Comment: only requirement. You'll probably have to consider gender, gender preference, geographic location, hobbies...you can even learn the person's taste, to increase the positive matches. This will require a very specific technology and data. Normally, what you'd do from your aggregates is publish an event, like MatchFinalized, and your Query system will listen to them and store the data in the right format that allows very efficient queries.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot answer the question about PushAll. An aggregate like Match would be very small, so I wouldn't worry about storing the whole document.

Comment: well I understand the point but I would need to call update anyway outside of this domain object... This is something that clearly EF core have fixed for us.

If I would say FinalizeMatch, the callee would after that action over the domain object need to call Builders.Update.. I just see some problems here I wasn't expecting to see. Probably I still don't understand this fully. I think this kind of problems are candidates for NoSQL but then other problems arrive whille for example DDD with ef core worked fine for a small number of clients, will not escalate too much.

Comment: I don't fully understand the issue. In my DDD applications, I have use cases that basically do: var aggregate = unitOfWork.GetById(someId); aggregate.DoBusinessOperation(someParameters); unitOfWork.Commit(); I have implementations of unit of work with relational and non relational dbs and they work the same way. I prefer to store aggregates in documents because I treat them as a single unit, so having multiple tables only adds complexity and no advantages.

Comment: Thanks man. I revisited this post again after a couple of days with more knowledge about DDD, Event Sourcing and NoSQL, and all added up. Cheers man!